# selection handle on mouse down behaving weirdly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a gap in the rectangle using the middle selection handle. I have two middle selection handles, If I select any of them it should create a gap in the middle like dividing the rectangle into 2 equal halves. ( like we have curtains in the play :P)

In my case the right selection handle is behaving in the same way as the left selection handle. if I am taking the middle selection handle to the right it should create a gap in the middle but instead its its creating an overlap.

Please select the green rectangle in the fiddle and try to select the one in the middle and move the same to the right side. It will not do the correct function . and instead if you select the middle handle and move it to the left it will be fine.

Please let me know where my logic is going wrong.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q582L/7/

Any help is really appreciated.

```
            switch (expectResize) {
            case 0:
                mySel.x = mx;
                mySel.y = my;
                mySel.w += oldx - mx;
                mySel.h += oldy - my;
                break;
            case 1:
                mySel.y = my;
                mySel.h += oldy - my;
                break;
             case 2:
                mySel.y = my;
                mySel.w = mx - oldx;
                mySel.h += oldy - my;
                break;
            case 3:
                mySel.x = mx;
                mySel.w += oldx - mx;
                break;
            case 4:
                mySel.w = mx - oldx;
                break;
            case 5:
                mySel.x = mx;
                mySel.w += oldx - mx;
                mySel.h = my - oldy;
                break;
            case 6:
                mySel.h = my - oldy;
                break;
            case 7:
                mySel.w = mx - oldx;
                mySel.h = my - oldy;
                break;
            case 8:

                //if(mx >= mySel.x + minGold)
               //     mx = mySel.x + minGold;

                // Enforce limits on mx:
                //     Should not be closer than 5 pixels to this.x (left side of metric box)
                //     Should not be > this.x + width/2 (middle of metric box)
                mySel.windowWidth = (mySel.x + mySel.w/2) - mx;
                console.log(mySel.windowWidth);
                break;
            case 9:
                // Enforce limits on mx:
                //     Should not be closer than 5 pixels to this.x (left side of metric box)
                //     Should not be > this.x + width/2 (middle of metric box)
                mySel.windowWidth = (mySel.x + mySel.w) - mx;
                console.log(mySel.windowWidth);
                break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the mouse is moving to the left to grow the window, you need this:

```
case 9: mySel.windowWidth = mx - (mySel.x + mySel.w / 2);
```

---

**EDIT**

A quick-fix to create limits would be something like this:

```
case 8:
    mySel.windowWidth = Math.max(Math.min((mySel.x + mySel.w/2) - mx, mySel.w - 5), 0);
    break;
case 9:
    mySel.windowWidth = Math.max(Math.min(mx - (mySel.x + mySel.w/2), mySel.w - 5), 0);
    break;
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/REED9/2/).

Comment: Hi @Teemu. Thanks for your reply.. I modified this a Bit and now there is no overlap of the width as well. How can I add the limitation of atleast 5 px of rectangle on both sides. ( there should not be only white space)  My latest fiddle is  http://jsfiddle.net/REED9/1/

Comment: I do not want the rectangle to have only gap there should be atleast 5 px of green rectangle on each side.

Comment: @user3191909 I've added some limits to the "curtain", but I'm afraid you've to re-think the math, since handles are not following the mouse accurately. Also you haven't implemented "curtain" resizing in a case user drags the rect smaller. Maybe ask a new question about these fixes?

Comment: I have added some fixes http://jsfiddle.net/q582L/18/ But still the last thing is I am not able to add the min green rectangle on left side. Can you pls look into this.

Comment: @user3191909 Now it looks good ; ). I can't locate your problem. What ever it is, please ask a new question about it. We are not supposed to extend questions/answers like this. Posts - especially answers - will become confusing for future visitors. Very few people read all the comment threads in a post. Then they see a lot of "irrelevant" stuff in an answer, which is not asked in the original question, and get confused.

Comment: Yes thank you for all your help.  I did ask a new question but no one replied to my question. IF you have time please take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790386/mouse-handles-are-not-in-sync-with-the-mouse